# Application.Run(form) never returns (after using System::Management)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-c++

I have a class library assembly that once loaded opens one form (form1) and when prompted form1 opens other forms(form2). Each form runs in a separate thread , this is because in each form runs a flashweave applicatin and for performance i need to run them in separate theads.
If i load the library using a managed loader written in c# everything works ok.
If i load the library using a mixed clr/c++ assembly , when a form2 gets closed Application.Run() dooesn't return resulting in many stuck threads.
I tried also to force abort the threads using Thread.Abort() but still the thread doesn't abort.
If i close form1 application.run() returns and it's thread can stop. 
I also tried to open simple empty forms instead of form2 without any flashwave object in them , and still it doesn't return.

Maybe the problem is connected with this message that i get sometime:

> The CLR has been unable to transition
>   from COM context 0x197060 to COM
>   context 0x196ef0 for 60 seconds. The
>   thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely
>   either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running
>   operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has
>   a negative performance impact and may
>   even lead to the application becoming
>   non responsive or memory usage
>   accumulating continually over time. To
>   avoid this problem, all single
>   threaded apartment (STA) threads
>   should use pumping wait primitives
>   (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and
>   routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

About form2 opening:

```
private void OpenTable()
{
            if (!this.InvokeRequired)
            {

                Thread TableRun = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OpenTable));
                TableRun.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
                TableRun.IsBackground = false;
                TableRun.Name = "T2"; 
                TableRun.Start();

                return;
            }
            try
            {
                FormTable T = new FormTable(;
                T.MyThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
                Application.Run(T);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
}
```

Stack trace for a stuck thread:

> ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForMultipleObjects@20()
>   + 0x15 byte       ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForMultipleObjects@20()
>   + 0x15 byte       KernelBase.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjectsEx@20()
>   + 0x36 byte       kernel32.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation@20()
>   + 0x8e byte       user32.dll!_RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx@20()
>   + 0xe2 byte       ole32.dll!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn()  +
>   0x96 byte
>     ole32.dll!_CoWaitForMultipleHandles@20()
>   - 0x51b9 byte     mscorwks.dll!NT5WaitRoutine()  + 0x39
>   byte      mscorwks.dll!MsgWaitHelper() 
>   + 0x97 byte       mscorwks.dll!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait()
>   - 0xf32e5 byte        mscorwks.dll!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker()
>   + 0x104 byte      mscorwks.dll!Thread::DoAppropriateWait()
>   + 0x40 byte       mscorwks.dll!CLREvent::WaitEx()  +
>   0x1438a9 byte
>     mscorwks.dll!CLREvent::Wait()  + 0x17
>   byte
>     mscorwks.dll!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWait()
>   + 0xec byte       mscorwks.dll!ReleaseRCWsInCaches()  +
>   0xe34fd byte
>     mscorwks.dll!ReleaseRCWsInCachesNoThrow()
>   + 0x67 byte       mscorwks.dll!Thread::CleanupCOMState()
>   + 0x1b8f83 byte       mscorwks.dll!Thread::OnThreadTerminate()
>   + 0x46 byte       mscorwks.dll!DestroyThread()  + 0x3b
>   byte
>     mscorwks.dll!ThreadNative::KickOffThread()
>   + 0xf2 byte       mscorwks.dll!Thread::intermediateThreadProc()
>   + 0x46 byte       kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()
>   + 0x12 byte

Regarding the code that shows the first thread is:

```
//c++ code
        Assembly::form^ f= gcnew Assembly::form() ; 
        f->Load();
        gcroot<Assembly::form^>* dsa3_gc_p= new gcroot<Assembly::form^>(f);
        this->obMainLib = (void *)dsa3_gc_p;
//------------------------
//The c++ loader just calls the Load() method
//c#library   
        public void Load()
                {
                    FormThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Start));
                    FormThread.Name = "T7";
                    FormThread.IsBackground = true;
                    FormThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    FormThread.Start();    
                }
        private void Start()
                {
                    Config = GlobalConfig.GetConfig(GlobalConfig.ConfigurationFile);
                    HttpInterface = new DHttpInterface(Config);
                    Lobby = new FormLobby(HttpInterface, false);


                    WorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Start));
                    WorkerThread.Name = "T6";
                    WorkerThread.IsBackground = true;
                    WorkerThread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
                    WorkerThread.Start();

                    Application.Run(Lobby);
                    Config.SaveToDisk();
                }
```

NEWS:
Finally i've found what generate this behaviour. Before instantiating the c# library, the loader try to get the cpu serial by using .net System::Management, if i remove such part then all works ok.
This is the guilty part:

```
std::string Loader::GetCPUID()
{
    std::string lsCPUID = "";
    try
    {
        System::Management::ManagementObjectCollection^ moReturn  = nullptr;
        System::Management::ManagementObjectSearcher^ moSearch  ;

        moSearch = gcnew System::Management::ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor");

        moReturn = moSearch->Get();
        for each ( System::Management::ManagementObject^ mo in moReturn )
        {
            char * chp = (char *) System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(mo["ProcessorID"]->ToString()).ToPointer();
            lsCPUID.assign(chp);
        }
    }
    catch(System::Exception^ ex )
    {
    }

    return lsCPUID;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How does T.MyThread not throw an NullReferenceException?

Comment: Why should it ?
However you can skip it... i just added it later to provide a reference to the thread and try to brutally abort it , but it ddidn't work.

Comment: oops i trimmed some unuseful parts , and i trimmed also the part where FormTable  gets instantiated... i'm going to edit it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the C++ code that you use to load your assembly and show the first form.

Comment: Use the debugger's Threads window to find out what it is doing.  Enable the Microsoft symbol server to get good stack traces.

Comment: Ok i loaded symbols , i'm going to add the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way. I created a new AppDomain in wich i ran the method to get the cpu serial and then unloaded that domain so the System::Management library that was causing problems got unloaded.

ref class MarshalByRefType : MarshalByRefObject
{
public:
    //  Call this method via a proxy.

```
std::string GetCPUID()
{
    //char * chp = (char *) System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(R671::R671::Value()).ToPointer();
    std::string lsCPUID = "";
    //return lsCPUID.assign(chp);
    try
    {
        System::Management::ManagementObjectCollection^ moReturn  = nullptr;
        System::Management::ManagementObjectSearcher^ moSearch  ;

        moSearch = gcnew System::Management::ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor");

        moReturn = moSearch->Get();
        for each ( System::Management::ManagementObject^ mo in moReturn )
        {
            char * chp = (char *) System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(mo["ProcessorID"]->ToString()).ToPointer();
            lsCPUID.assign(chp);
        }
    }
    catch(System::Exception^ ex )
    {
    }
    AppDomainSetup^ ads = AppDomain::CurrentDomain->SetupInformation;
    String^ str = String::Format("AppName={0}, AppBase={1}, ConfigFile={2}", 
        ads->ApplicationName, 
        ads->ApplicationBase, 
        ads->ConfigurationFile);

    char * chp = (char *) System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str).ToPointer();
    lsCPUID.assign(chp);
    return lsCPUID;
}
```

}

```
class Loader
{
  std::string  GetCPUID()
    {
        String^ callingDomainName = Thread::GetDomain()->FriendlyName;

        // Construct and initialize settings for a second AppDomain.
        AppDomainSetup^ ads = gcnew AppDomainSetup();
        ads->ApplicationBase = 
            "file:///" +  Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location;
        ads->DisallowBindingRedirects = false;
        ads->DisallowCodeDownload = true;
        ads->ConfigurationFile = 
            AppDomain::CurrentDomain->SetupInformation->ConfigurationFile;

        // Create the second AppDomain.
        AppDomain^ ad2 = AppDomain::CreateDomain("AD #2", 
            AppDomain::CurrentDomain->Evidence, ads);
        String^ sam = R671::R671::typeid->FullName;
        // Create an instance of MarshalbyRefType in the second AppDomain. 
        // A proxy to the object is returned.
        MarshalByRefType^ mbrt = 
            (MarshalByRefType^) ad2->CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
            Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location, 
                MarshalByRefType::typeid->FullName
            );
        string lsCPUID;
        //char * chp = (char *) System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(mbrt2->Value()).ToPointer();
        lsCPUID = mbrt->GetCPUID();
        try
        {
            AppDomain::Unload(ad2);
        }   
        catch ( AppDomainUnloadedException^ /*e*/ ) 
        {

        }

        return lsCPUID;
    }

    void Load()
    {
        //do things
        std:string cpuid = this->GetCPUID();
        //do things
        //load c# library and open forms
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are calling OpenTable from an MTA thread, which InvokeRequired returns true, therefore instead of creating another STA thread, it goes straight to calling Application.Run() on the MTA thread?

Try calling Application.Run() from an STA thread instead...

Comment: No , all threads are STA threads. And also that thread can't be an MTA thread because it's the thread of form1.